# Weird iptables configuration?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

My iptables configuration has been set to the following after some update

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

which prevents me from accessing the internet and I have to reset it manually every time start my laptop. Tbh I do not know if the configuration was actually changed or just stopped working. I have been searching a lot online but did not manage to find a solution. How can I find out what changed my settings, and how to change them back to a working configuration and make it persistent. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using nordvpn and accidentally I found out that when connecting to the service it manipulates the iptables. Some of the rules it puts look really similar to the ones in my question. Deleting the nordvpn app fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try entering 'iptables -F' and then the rules you desire and save the rules by running these commands: `iptables --save;service iptables save` 
If that doesn't work, you could try making a file full of the rules you want then execute that file on boot using /etc/rc.local (thats what i do)